# Variable undefined when used outside of component constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, electron

I'm working on a project with React and Electron and have an error. I have a component with a constructor that takes in props (which come in the form of two variables.) The constructor is instantiated in a separate file. The issue is that the variable works fine (for instance if do `console.log` to output it) in the constructor, but outside of it, the variables comes back undefined.

I've already tried using `.bind` to bind it, but that didn't help and it still turned up as undefined.

This is where the constructor is called:

```
const dropDown = new Dropdown({
  editor,
  monaco
});
```

Here is the constructor and an example of where I am trying to use the variables:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // Define variables
  this.editor = props.editor;
  this.monaco = props.monaco;
  // Returns correct object
  console.log(this.monaco);

  // Bind functions
  this.changeLanguage = this.changeLanguage.bind(this);
  this.filterFunction = this.filterFunction.bind(this);
  this.dropDown = this.dropDown.bind(this);
}

changeLanguage(language) {
  // Returns undefined all the time
  console.log(this.monaco);
  this.monaco.editor.setModelLanguage(this.editor, language);
}
```

I expect the variable to be the same in both the constructor and the functions elsewhere in the file, yet for some reason, it's only defined in the constructor.

Comment: If this is React, and the constructor is for a react component, then at a minimum `this.props.monaco` should work, even if you don't save anything to `this.state`.  Based on what you describe it doesn't sound like you're using React correctly.  It's incredibly weird that you'd try to instantiate a react component before that actual component has been imported.  Can you provide a working example/snippet of your code for examination?

Comment: @DrewReese The issue is that `this.props.monaco` works when I use it inside the constructor but in the function `changeLanguage` it doesn't. And sorry if this wasn't clear, but I'm not instantiating it before it's imported, it's something different. That part isn't really relevant, I'll remove it. By working example do you want the whole file or something? It's a large project (lots of files) so I can't really upload it to jsfiddle or anything like that.

Comment: @t0xic He means create a [minimal, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.props.monaco. Or you can pass the props to the changeLanguage function if you rewrite it

```
changeLanguage(language, props) {
  // Returns undefined all the time
  console.log(props.monaco);
  props.monaco.editor.setModelLanguage(this.editor, language);
}
```

and call it: `this.changeLanguage('English', this.props)`